# Java Regex and json

Tags: java, regex, json

i have the following regex in place to validate the name field in my program and it works fine

```
^[a-zA-Z\\d\\s_.@\\-]*$
```

`{"name":"jfhgjhf"}`

I now want to add an embedded json element that I am passing in as part of my json (I am using Schema Form)
I want my taskDetails element to accept the same charachters as name as well as the charachters {[/:="

I tried the following regex with no joy

```
^[a-zA-Z\\d\\s_.@\\-{\\]\\[}/\\\\/\\/ ':=]*$

{"name":"jfhgjhf","taskDetails":"{\"ids\":[{\"id\":\"jhgjghjghfjf\"}]}"}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Why don't you use a [JSON parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)?

Comment: its not possible or doesnt make sense in this project. I want to store the json in 1 field in my db table .It makes sense for my project and how I am using schema form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the work

```
^[a-zA-Z\d\s_.@{\\}\/ ':=",\[\]-]*$
```

`-` must be final char because it can recognize for example `a-z`

[http://regexr.com/](http://regexr.com/3annm)

Comment: @FlorianLefèvre `.` doesn't need to be escaped (it has no special meaning in a character class). `-` does not need to be escaped, like OP mentions, at the beginning or end of a character class since `[-x]` and `[x-]` are obviously not ranges.

Comment: You're right, in character class `.` has no special meaning... Learned something today ! :) Thanks.